# Overwriting old sifr.js file results in uppercase text

Tags: sifr

I'm using sIFR 2.0.6 with the sifr.js file from 2.0.7 to resolve this issue: http://novemberborn.net/sifr/2.0.7.

In all browsers, before overwriting the sifr.js file, the sIFR displayed with initial caps. With the new sifr.js file in place, the text is all uppercased.

This is the only code I am customizing:

> if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
>       sIFR();
>       sIFR.replaceElement(".sifr-container",
>   named({sFlashSrc: "frutiger.swf",
>   sColor: "#042e66", sCase: "lower",
>   sWmode: "transparent",
>   background-color: "transparent"})); };

sCase doesn't appear to be doing the trick. How else can I control the uppercasing?

Thanks!

- Veda

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `background-color` like that in the replacement syntax. You sure that's correct?

Try inspecting the Flash movie's embed element to see if the text is uppercase or normal case when going into the Flash movie. You might want to try recreating the Flash movie as well.